# Validation rule that includes multi picklist field

Tags: formula, validation-rule, account, multi-select, stagename

I need help with a Validation rule that basically says if `Account Type = Customer`, and you want to set `Account Stage = On going`, you have to make sure first that multi picklist field does not contain the value `Do not Know`

Is the formula so far, it doesn't work.

```
ISPICKVAL (Type, "Customer")
&&
ISPICKVAL(Stages__c, "On Going")
&&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_picklist, "Do not Know"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this...

AND(
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Customer"),
ISCHANGED(Onboarding_Stages__c),
ISPICKVAL(Onboarding_Stages__c,"On Going"),

AND(OR(
INCLUDES(AB_Testing__c, "Do not Know"))
etc etc etc

Answer (score 3):

Validation rule trigger when the result is true, so you essentially have to list off every possible value:

```
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Customer") &&
ISPICKVAL(Stage__c,"On Going") &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 1")) &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 2")) &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 3")) &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 4")) &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 5")) &&
NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 6")) ...
```

This would probably be better written in Apex, because at least in Apex, it's a simple string to compare to. Given the limitations of multi-valued picklists in Validation Rules, it's not particularly efficient to work with them for rules like this.

Answer (score 0):

TEXT(Type) = 'Customer' && ISCHANGED(Stages__c) && TEXT(Stages__c) = 'On Going' && NOT(INCLUDES(Multi_picklist, 'Do not Know'))

Comment: IT didt work, now it doesnt let me save the record if I try to save the Multipicklist with anything other than Do not Know and don't have stage On Going selected, it gives me an error